# Swift Firebase Dynamic Links: shortenURL not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

facing some issue to generate shortenURL from firebase dynamic-links , I am able to get longDynamicLink url . but

here is my code , I am using https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create following steps DynamicLinkComponents.shortenURL completion not getting call and there is no error also

```
guard let longDynamicLink = linkBuilder.url else { return "test" }
print("The long URL is: \(longDynamicLink)")

DynamicLinkComponents.shortenURL(longDynamicLink, options: nil) { url, warnings, error in
    guard let url = url, error != nil else { return }
    print("The short URL is: \(url)")
}
```

DynamicLinkComponents.shortenURL this part is not executing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This Code. This Code Working Fine For Me.

```
    let shareLink:String = "http://YourURL"

    guard let newSharelink = URL(string: shareLink) else { return }
    let components = DynamicLinkComponents.init(link: newSharelink, domain: "Your Domin From Genrated By Google Account(EX. = napu4u.app.goo.gl)")
    let iOSParams = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "YourBundle ID")
    iOSParams.appStoreID = "Your AppStore ID (Optional)"

    components.iOSParameters = iOSParams
    let options = DynamicLinkComponentsOptions()
    options.pathLength = .short
    components.options = options

    components.shorten { (shortURL, warnings, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let shortLink = shortURL
        print(shortLink)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this to to App Capabilities - Associated Domains and enter - applinks:yourdomain.com

[image]

2. In your ViewController add

   ```
   guard let link = URL(string: "https://www.yourdomain.com/share_location.html?Id=\(RandomID)&uid=\(uid)") else { return }
       let dynamicLinksDomain = "yourdomain.page.link"


       let components = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domain: dynamicLinksDomain)
       // [START shortLinkOptions]
       let options = DynamicLinkComponentsOptions()
       options.pathLength = .unguessable
       components.options = options
       // [END shortLinkOptions]

       // [START shortenLink]
       components.shorten { (shortURL, warnings, error) in
           // Handle shortURL.
           if let error = error {
               print(error.localizedDescription)
               return
           }
           print(shortURL?.absoluteString ?? "")
           self.shortLink = shortURL
       }
   ```